# Can't Remove Data because of Child Reference Error?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user structure where I can create and update a user but I cannot remove a user due to a reference child error due to some kind of string.

Basically, I have a realtime database consists of different users ID then there's the Name, Age and Nationlaity.

[image: HTML Error]

[image: Firebase Users]

I want to be able to try and delete a user by its user ID for instance (usr5) so that when I enter that it'll delete the user from the database.

Can anyone help?

**The Error:**

```
Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object HTMLInputElement]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
at fi (validation.ts:382)
at o.child (Reference.ts:90)
at removeUser ((fie path folders) index.html:115:58)
```

**My HTML:**

```
<body>

    <div>
        <h4>Create User: </h4>

            <form>
                <label>Create User ID: </label><input type="text" id="usrID"/><br/>
                <label>First Name: </label><input type="text" id="usrFName"/><br/>
                <label>Age: </label><input type="number" id="usrAge"/><br/>
                <label>Nationality: </label>
                    <select id="usrNation">
                        <option value="American">American</option>
                        <option value="British">British</option>
                        <option value="French">French</option>
                    </select>
                <button id="createUserBtn">Create</button>              
            </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h4>Remove User: </h4>

            <form>
                <label>Create User ID: </label><input type="text" id="usrID"/><br/>
                <button id="removeUserBtn">Remove</button>              
            </form>
    </div>
```

**My Firebase/Javascript:**

```
<script>

var database = new Firebase("https://(my db url)/"),

    userdb = database.child("/users");

    userID = document.getElementById('usrID'),
    userFirstName = document.getElementById('usrFName'),
    userAge = document.getElementById('usrAge'),
    userNationality = document.getElementById('usrNation');


function createUser(userID, usrFName, usrAge, usrNation){
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
        usrFName: usrFName,
        usrAge: usrAge,
        usrNation: usrNation            
    });

    console.log('Success');
}

function insertAutoKey(usrFName, usrAge, usrNation){

    var newPost = {
        usrFName: usrFName,
        usrAge: usrAge,
        usrNation: usrNation
    };

    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

    var updates = {};
    updates['/users/' + newPostKey] = newPost;
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}

document.getElementById('createUserBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){

    var usrID = userID.value,
        usrFName = userFirstName.value,
        usrAge = userAge.value,
        usrNation = userNationality.value;

    if(usrID && usrFName && usrAge && usrNation) {
        createUser(usrID, usrFName, usrAge, usrNation);
    }       
});

function removeUser(){
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(userID);

    userRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.val() === null) {
            alert("no user found");
        }else{
            userRef.remove();
        }
    });
    console.log('Remove Success');
}

document.getElementById('removeUserBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    removeUser();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
userID          = document.getElementById('usrID'),
userFirstName   = document.getElementById('usrFName'),
userAge         = document.getElementById('usrAge'),
userNationality = document.getElementById('usrNation');
```

into this:

```
userID          = document.getElementById('usrID').value;
userFirstName   = document.getElementById('usrFName').value;
userAge         = document.getElementById('usrAge').value;
userNationality = document.getElementById('usrNation').value;
```

You need to add the property `value` to retrieve the value of each element.

Comment: Still retrieiving the same error but I already defined the value property inside the createUserBtn

Comment: in createUserBtn `document.getElementById('createUserBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){

    var usrID = userID.value,
        usrFName = userFirstName.value,
        usrAge = userAge.value,
        usrNation = userNationality.value;

    if(usrID && usrFName && usrAge && usrNation) {
        createUser(usrID, usrFName, usrAge, usrNation);
    }       
});` `userID` is a local variable here.

Comment: If `createUser` is working then after adding `value` the function `removeUser` should work also. Because now according to the error, you are getting an html element in the `child()`

Comment: Its used for entering the user id the problem seems to be in the remove than the create area?

Comment: createUser works fine but doesn't work on the removeUser

Comment: yes the problem is in `removeUser`.. do this `function removeUser(){
    var deleteUser = userID.value;
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(deleteUser);

    userRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.val() === null) {
            alert("no user found");
        }else{
            userRef.remove();
        }
    });
    console.log('Remove Success');
}`

Comment: Tried that but still gives me the same error. I also tried to the code inside the button it doesn't have problems just not deleting the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190981/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-thomasjh).

Comment: Peter, the issue seems to be something to the path of the data store. Although the function is working by displaying 'No User Found' its not removing the data from the database

function removeUser(userID){ 
 
//var deleteUser = userID.value;
var userRef = firebase.database().ref('/users').child('/users/ + userID');

 userRef.once('value', function(snapshot) { 
  if (snapshot.val() === null) { 
   alert("no user found"); 
  }else{
   userRef.remove();
  }
 });
 console.log('Remove Success');
}